# What is the correct behavior of non ascii chars in printf format?

Tags: c, mingw

So I had this c windows program that writes to a data file with this code.

```
  fprintf(fo,"\xbf%06d",num) ;
```

It worked fine but at some Chinese computers it behaves differently. 
I made a little test program in C and compiled it in borland C and mingw.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)  {
  int i = 0 ;
  unsigned char b[100] ;
  sprintf(b,"\xbf%d",12345) ;
  printf("\n%s\n",b) ;
  while (b[i]) 
    printf(" %02X",b[i++]) ;
  printf("\n") ;
}
```

on my computer the output is :

```
┐12345
BF 31 32 33 34 35
```

But if I let my Chinese client test it on his computer it worked differently for the Borland version:
The output is:

```
?d
 BF 25 64
```

Apparently the xbf and ? are combined to one Chinese character.

In China the output of the program compiled with mingw is:

```
?2345
 BF 31 32 33 34 35
```

Here the format is parsed one byte at a time.

Which one is the correct behaviour?
How do other C/C++ compilers handle this?

Comment: You might want to choose between C and C++.

Comment: It might not be specified by the C standard, but by your operating system. See [utf8everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: Does the format string in the `sprintf` statement literally include `\xbf`, or does it include the character `┐`? If it says `\xbf`, then I think your client's compiler is buggy. If you used the character `┐`, then try again with the hex escape.

Comment: A different problem is creating a file using a particular Windows codepage and trying to process it on a different machine whose default locale is UTF-8 or some other encoding. That's a data transmission problem, not a probkem with how printf works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is happening with your Borland compiler, but use wide chars to deal with extended characters like chinese:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i = 0 ;
    wchar_t b[100] ;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    swprintf(b, 100, L"\xbf%d", 12345);
    wprintf(L"\n%s\n", b);
    while (b[i]) 
        wprintf(L" %02X", b[i++]);
    wprintf(L"\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I never had the intention to write Chinese. My problem is that a data-file ends up differently at some client computers.

Comment: @archimedes Sure it is, you are trying to write wide chars with standard functions that do not support it correctly. This answer show you how to correctly write wide chars. If it's not your need, then you may have badly express your problem.

Comment: Yes, even if you are not writting chinese, this `"\xbf"` is an extended character (not in the range 0 ... 127 of the ASCII table)

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the first case your console output uses a cp**** (one byte = one char) encoding while in the second case it uses UTF8 encoding. Note that 0xbf byte code (as well as any byte code above 127) requires the next one or more bytes to be consumed in order to provide extra bits to the code of the same UTF8-encoded character.

What to do depends on your task. If you don't really need to print any characters not included into ascii-128 set (Latin + digits + 'ordinary' punctuation and whatever you can find at an English keyboard + control characters), you shouldn't care - it will work in any locale. Otherwise, set a locale explicitly and use wide characters (still, as far as I can understand, it isn't necessary in your case).